# I am getting AssertionError: Element openerp has extra content: data, line 2

Tags: odoo-9

I am trying to install a module, then I am getting below error.

AssertionError: Element openerp has extra content: data, line 2

What type of mistake I did for getting this error.

In which file I have to search for error rectify. I am using odoo9.

Files:

**This is my xmlfile.xml**

```
<data>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="10">

<field name="name">model.name</field>

<field name="model">smp.model2</field>

<field name="arch" type="xml">

<form>

<sheet>

<group colspan="4">

<group colspan="2" cal="2">

<field name="name"/>

<field name="active"/>

</group>

<group colspan="2" cal="2">

<field name="age"/>

<field name="sal"/>

</group>

<group colspan="2" cal="2">

<field name="adharid"/>

<field name="cell"/>

</group>

<notebook colspan="4">

<page string="extrainfo"><field name="extrainfo"/></page>

<page string="temporaryaddress"><field name="temporaryaddress"/></page>

<page string="perminantaddress"><field name="perminantaddress"/></page>

</notebook> 

</group>

</sheet>

</form>

</field>

</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="20">

<field name="name">model.name</field>

<field name="model">smp.model2</field>

<field name="arch" type="xml">

<tree>

<field name="name"/>

<field name="active"/>

<field name="age"/>

<field name="sal"/>

<field name="adharid"/>

<field name="cell"/>

<field name="extrainfo"/>

<field name="temporaryaddress"/>

<field name="perminantaddress"/>

</tree>

</field>

</record>

<record model ="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_smp_model2">

<field name="name">sampmodel</field>

<field name="res_model">smp.model2</field>

<field name="view_type">form</field>

<field name="viwe_mode">tree,form</field>

</record>

<menuitem id="smp_main_menu1" name="smp model2"/>

<menuitem id="subsmp_main_menu1" name="Sub sample model"
   parent="smp_main_menu1"/>

<menuitem id="actsmp_main_menu" name="action smp model"
parent="subsmp_main_menu1" action="action_smp_model2"/>

</data>

</openerp>
```

**This is my data.xml file**

```
<data>

<record id='1' name="smp.model2">

<filed name="name">name1</filed>

<filed name="age">23</filed>

<filed name="cell">123456434</filed>

</record>

<record id='2' name="smp.model2">

<filed name="name">name1</filed>

<filed name="age">23</filed>

<filed name="cell">123456434</filed>

</record>

<record id='3' name="smp.model2">

<filed name="name">name1</filed>

<filed name="age">23</filed>

<filed name="cell">123456434</filed>

</record>

</data>

</openerp>
```

**This is python_file.py**

```
from openerp import models,fields

class model2(models.Model):

_name="smp.model2"

name=fields.Char(string="model name", requred=True, help="name of the 

model")

active=fields.Boolean(String="Active")

age=fields.Integer(string="person age",help="age of person")

sal=fields.Integer(string="sal")

adharid=fields.Integer(string="Adhar Id")

cell=fields.Integer(string="phone number",requred=True)

extrainfo=fields.Text(string="Extra information")

temporaryaddress=fields.Text(string="Temporary address")

perminantaddress=fields.Text(string="perminant address")
```

**This is __openerp__.py file**

```
{

    'name':'module12',

    'description':'module12',

    'author':'naveen',

    'version':'9.0',

    'depends':['base'],

    'data':['xmlfile.xml','data.xml']
}
```

Comment: Please answer me asap...

Comment: I have same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

you have errors in a xml, example:

`requred=True` is `required=True`

`<filed` is `<field`